# .hide() on "this" generated img element

Tags: jquery

```
    $.each(hand, function( index, value ) {
        var img = $('<img /">').attr({'src': "images/"+value+".png"}).appendTo($('#myHand')).click(function(){this.hide()
        });
    });
```

I am using this code to generate a bunch of images in a div. The code is working, however, when I click an image I want it to become hidden, so what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `this` value isin't a jQuery object, it's a DOM object inside the handler.

Try: `$(this).hide();`

Also it isin't very efficient to attach an handler to every img elements. You could use event delegation to handle them all with a single handler on the parent of all images.

```
$('#parent').on('click', 'img', function (e) {
    $(e.currentTarget).hide();
});
```